# C# - Entity Framework not updating Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a simple app which performs standard CRUD operations.

My issue is that at the moment, it does not seem to be editing values in the database. I have debugged through the process and seen that it fails on the `set.Attach(entity)` line in the context.

**Model**

```
[Table("RepackRequest")]
public partial class RepackRequest
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public RepackRequest()
    {
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FromItem { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ToItem { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public int? QuantityCompleted { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime DateRequested { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RequestedBy { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RequestedByEmail { get; set; }

    public string ActionRequired { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Division { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Priority { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string EnteredBy { get; set; }

    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }

    public string FromLocation { get; set; }

    public string ToLocation { get; set; }

    public string ReworkedBy { get; set; }

    public string OriginalDriver { get; set; }

    public string FromItemDriver { get; set; }

    public string FromLocationDriver { get; set; }

    public string ToLocationDriver { get; set; }

    public string Workforce { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OrderNum { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime PlannedCompletion { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

}
```

**API Controller Action**

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/Repack/Update")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateRepack([FromBody] RepackRequest repack)
{
    var oldStatus = _uow.RepackService.Get(repack.ID).Status;
    _uow.RepackService.UpdateRepack(repack);
    _uow.Save();
    if (repack.Status == "C")
        await _helper.SendCompletedRepackEmail(repack);
    else if (repack.Status != oldStatus)
        await _helper.SendStatusChangeEmail(repack, oldStatus);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, repack.ID);
}
```

**Service Method**

```
public void UpdateRepack(RepackRequest repack)
{
    _context.SetModified(repack);
    _context.Save(); //_context.SaveChanges() called inside here
}
```

**Context Method**

```
public void SetModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    var set = Set<T>();
    set.Attach(entity); //FAILS HERE
    Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

I have checked that the ID etc of the object is filled so that Entity Framework can find the existing record and im now out of ideas.

I dont get any error messages at all. All i see is that once it tries to attach the entity, it goes to the `Dispose()` method of my UnityResolver.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: What's the exception type, message etc... ?

Comment: Hi sorry i missed that info off. Ive now updated my question but there was no error or exception. It just goes to the Dispose method of my UnityResolver

Comment: did you try _context.SaveChanges() ?

Comment: SaveChanges is called inside the _context.Save(); method called from the UpdateRepack service method. However, it doesnt get to this point as it fails to attach the entity

Comment: I have commented the line of code where it is called just to clarify

Comment: Wrap what's inside the SetModified method into try catch and try to log the exception.

Comment: "Attaching an entity of type 'RepackLog.DAL.Models.RepackRequest' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

Comment: This kind of makes sense but kind of doesnt. Do i need to check if the entity is already attached before attaching it when modifying?

Comment: No, the thing is that you're trying to attach an entity that doesn't belong to the context. you need to bring that object by key, modify the fetched object then attach and save (or just save it)

Comment: so instead of using the entity that ive passed through from my app, i need to fetch the entity from the database, update the changed values determined by what is passed through to the API and then save it? These seems very long winded or am i misunderstanding? Could you give an example of what you mean please

Comment: That's exactly what I meant and what you need to do. If you want to understand this further try to check the types by debugging like: `var xFetched = typeof(ctx.WhatEver.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault()); var xDomain = typeof(entity);`. You'll see that EF creates a custom type for entities that could be managed by the DbContext

Comment: can you confirm the State of the entry before you set it to modified?

Comment: @HadiHassan the state is detached before trying to attach

Comment: @Fourat Could you give an example of how to do this as there is quite a few properties on the model and ive never had to directly check each one before so seems a little overkill. of course i will do it if thats what has to be done but is there a method or some code to automatically update values based on another object rather than going through the model property by property?

Comment: I think the problem not in the SetModified method, the problem started from the Get it self, can you try the following? try to load the data with AsNoTracking() and then confirm if any error occured?

Comment: Sorry what is AsNoTracking() and how do i incorporate it? ive not heard of that method before

Comment: this method will stop tracking the object inside the context, to use it, add reference to `System.Data.Entity` and this method is good for you later in application performance

Comment: @DaRoGa there's a method within the Entry class I think it's `Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(entityFromController);` but I like it or use it, you may want to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self describing. The reason is that you get entity from context before attaching it by this `var oldStatus = _uow.RepackService.Get(repack.ID).Status;` code line and Entity Framework keeps it in context. You have two workarounds:

### First

In your `UpdateRepack` re-get the entity from context using its id and set the values to new values.

```
public void UpdateRepack(RepackRequest repack)
{
    RepackRequest fromDatabase = _uow.RepackService.Get(repack.ID);
    // Set current values to new values.
    _context.SetValues(fromDatabase, repack);
    _context.Save(); //_context.SaveChanges() called inside here
}

public void SetValues<T>(T entity, T currentEntity) where T : class
{
    var entry = Entry(entity);
    entry.CurrentValues.SetValues(currentEntity);
}
```

Do not worry, getting data from context will not be costly operation, because it is already in the context. By using this method update query will be sent to update only changed properties, whereas if you set state of entity to modified then update query will be sent to update all column values.

### Second (not recommended)

You can use `AsNoTracking` to tell EntityFramework not to store received entity in the context. But by doing so, *every time* you try to get object query will be executed against database. Additionally update query will be sent to update all column values and it much expensive than updating only needed values. To do so, you should add another method to `RepackService` of unit of work called `GetAsNoTracking` and implement it similar to below:

```
public Repack GetAsNoTracking(int id)
{
    return _context.Set<Repack>()
        .AsNoTracking()
        .First(m => m.ID == id);    
}
```

Then you should use `GetAsNoTracking` to get your repack and not touch to remaining part of your current code. As it is not stored in context attaching it will not cause to an error.

```
[HttpPost, Route("api/Repack/Update")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UpdateRepack([FromBody] RepackRequest repack)
{
    var oldStatus = _uow.RepackService.GetAsNoTracking(repack.ID).Status;
    .........
}
```

**Note:** It is not good practice to save data for every operation. In *Unit of Work pattern* you are supposed to commit one time instead of calling `SaveChanges` method for every action. From your code I see that you have `_uow.Save();` method and I believe that you call `_context.SaveChanges()` method inside this method. By doing so, you should avoid calling `SaveChanges` at crud functions such as `UpdateRepack` method.

```
public void UpdateRepack(RepackRequest repack)
{
    // Do needed operations
    // Remove this line. You are supposed to save changes in the end using _uow.Save(); -> _context.Save(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to attach an entity that doesn't belong to the context. you need to bring that object by key, modify the fetched object then attach and save (or just save it). More details [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-entity-in-entity-framework.aspx)

You're code should be something like (as discussed in the comments):

```
public void SetModified<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    var set = Set<T>();
    var entityFromCtx = set.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
    Entry(entityFromCtx).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    //set.Attach(entity); // you don't need this anymore since you're not disposing the context yet.
    Entry(entityFromCtx).State = EntityState.Modified;
    //set.SaveChanges(); // I don't know if this fits here, but just don't forget it.
}
```